# Java mail create DSN (Delivered Status Notification)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to create DSN (delivered status notification) and send back to sender. I use MimeMulitPartReport and add 3 part of body. However, it does not work. In the recipient side, it does not show a human readable message and DSN information. I can't figure out, what's wrong in my code.

Thank you

Comment: Your code might help to track down the Problem.

Comment: Here is Code: MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);  MimeMultipartReport multipart = new MimeMultipartReport (); multipart.setReportType ("delivery-status"); DNSMimeBodyPart bodyPart = new DNSMimeBodyPart(MimeMessage); MimeBodyPart part1 = bodyPart.CreateTextMessage(); multipart.addBodyPart(part1); // Part1 is human readable text. MimeBodyPart part2 = bodyPart.createDSN(remoteHost); multipart.addBodyPart(part2); Part2 is create DSN (Delivered status notification). MimeBodyPart part3 = bodyPart.createAttachedOriginal(HEAD); multipart.addBodyPart(part3); msg.setContent(multipart);

Comment: Continue code... msg.setHeader(RFC2822Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, multipart.getContentType()); msg.setSubject("test"); msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("test@hotmail.com")); if (msg.getHeader(RFC2822Headers.DATE) == null){if (msg.getHeader(RFC2822Headers.DATE) == null){msg.setHeader(RFC2822Headers.DATE, new RFC822DateFormat().format(new Date()));} InternetAddress add = new InternetAddress(); add.setAddress("my@gmail.com"); add.setPersonal("test status system"); Transport.send(msg); But it can't show Part1, Part2 and Part3 in recipient side.

Answer (score 1):

I use JavaMail 1.4.5 with DSN extension http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-141777.html :

```
private MimeMessage dsnEmail() throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    MultipartReport multipart = new MultipartReport(
            HUMAN_READABLE_MSG,
            new DeliveryStatus(),
            originalEmail
    );
    msg.setContent(multipart);
    msg.setSubject("Delivery Status Notification (failure)");
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, originalEmail.getSender());
    return msg;
}
```

with this maven import :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>dsn</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: If i use your code how can i track whether the mail is sent | pending | Failure ?